# npm run build on Unknown option: C:\library\my-app\node_modules\babel-preset-react-app\index.js.overrides

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs

I am trying to publish a react package but am failing at the point of building my package. I have looked at numerous stackoverflow and other internet sites mentioning the issue but I have not found an answer for me.

My package.json

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.21.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-select": "^5.8.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production babel src/lib --out-dir dist --copy-files --ignore __tests__,spec.js,test.js,__snapshots__",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3"
  }
}
```

When I run npm run build I get the error

```
ReferenceError: [BABEL] src\lib\program.js: Unknown option: C:\library\my-app\node_modules\babel-preset-react-app\index.js.overrides. Check out http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/ for more information about options.

A common cause of this error is the presence of a configuration options object without the corresponding preset name. Example:

Invalid:
  `{ presets: [{option: value}] }`
Valid:
  `{ presets: [['presetName', {option: value}]] }`
```

I have the following babel config
.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [["react-app", { "absoluteRuntime": false }]]
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Looked at various sites. Removed node_modules and reran npm install. Still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to make a habit of asking a question and then answering it myself.
I have spent 3 days on this issue trying various things. As soon as I posted the question, I read some more articles and one gave me a clue. VERSION numbers.

From the errors I was getting, the babel modules seemed not to be compatible with my setup.

Originally I had the following in package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"cross-env": "^7.0.3"
```

}

babel-cli and babel-preset-react were the wrong versions. What I needed were the latest versions which are in the scoped versions of the babel modules

```
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/cli": "^7.23.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.23.3",
"cross-env": "^7.0.3"
```

}

Now it all works fine.

What have I learnt? When following an example of "how to" check its date and whatever it is using see if it the version that will work for you.